# Ошибка при отправке POST-запроса с помощью fetch в NODEJS

Tags: node.js, кириллица

Создаю Телеграм-бота через которого клиент может отрправлять запросы на сторонний API для получения информации по товарам и заказам. Бэкенд NodeJS с Express.

Всё работает ОК, пока в URl не приходится включать кириллицу - названия товаров или номера заказов (как на примере ниже).

При вот таком POST запросе - [https://somewebsite.ru/api/v1/order.json?orderId=МУЗ97008058](https://somewebsite.ru/api/v1/order.json?orderId=%D0%9C%D0%A3%D0%9797008058)

Вылетает ошибка: TypeError [ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS]: Request path contains unescaped characters

Я попытался использовать encodeURI() для номера заказа (МУЗ97008058)
Ошибка меняется на:
FetchError: invalid json response body at https://somewebsite.ru/api/v1/order.json?orderId=%D0%9C%D0%A3%D0%97008058 reason: Unexpected end of JSON input

При использовании Postman все работает прекрасно, никаких ошибок. Я просто вставляю полный URL и отправляю запрос [https://somewebsite.ru/api/v1/order.json?orderId=МУЗ97008058](https://somewebsite.ru/api/v1/order.json?orderId=%D0%9C%D0%A3%D0%9797008058) и всё отрабатывает корректно, сервер присылает ответ.

На самом сервере кодировка utf8, использую WebStorm и VS Code - в обеих кодировка UTF8

Вот код:

```
oneOrder: async (orderNumber) => {
    try {
        let url = `https://somewebsite.ru/api/v1/order.json?orderId=${orderNumber}`
        return fetch(url, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(answer => {
            if (answer.error) {
                return answer.message
            } else if (answer.orderId) {
                return `Номер заказа: ${answer['orderId']}\nСоздан ${answer['createdAt']}\nОбщая стоимость товаров в заказе: ${answer['totalCost']}\nСтатус оплаты: ${answer['status']['payment']}\nСтатус доставки: ${answer['status']['delivey']}`
            }
            return 'Нет информации по заказу'
        })

    } catch (e) {
        console.log('ERROR with oneOrder function:', e)
    }
},
```

Заранее спасибо и извиняюсь, если я упустил что-то очень простое и очевидное.

Comment: `При вот таком POST запросе - https://somewebsite.ru/api/v1/order.json?orderId=МУЗ97008058` это - POST в котором данные передаются в query string. А посылать данные нужно в `body: JSON.stringify({orderId: 'МУЗ97008058'})`

Comment: Поробовал отправить POST на "https://somewebsite.ru/api/v1/order.json?", а в options: {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({orderId: 'МУЗ97008058'})
            } - сервер не увидел body

Comment: сделал fetch(url + new URLSearchParams({orderId: 'МУЗ97008058'})) - получил  FetchError: invalid json response body at &orderId=%D0%9C%D0%A3%D0%97008058 - все равно кириллица превращается в юникод и сервер это не понимает...

Comment: а покажите роут, который обрабатывает ваш запрос

Comment: роут на сервере с API не смогу показать, нет к нему доступа((

Comment: тогда попробуйте `fetch('', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
  },
  body: 'orderId=%D0%9C%D0%A3%D0%9797008058'})`

Comment: Сработало! fetch('', {   method: 'POST',   headers: {     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'   },   body: 'orderId=%D0%9C%D0%A3%D0%9797008058'}) Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы не отправляете файлы то есть всего два тривиальных варианта того, что ожидает получить somewebsite.ru в виде данных POST-запроса.

#### Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

```
fetch(
  'https://somewebsite.ru/api/v1/order.json',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({orderId: 'МУЗ97008058'}).toString()
  }
)
```

#### Content-Type': 'application/json'

```
fetch(
  'https://somewebsite.ru/api/v1/order.json',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({orderId: 'МУЗ97008058'})
  }
)
```

Один из них сработает!